# Cassandra coexistence 1.1.x and 1.2.x

Tags: cassandra

We're running Cassandra version 1.1.10 on two data centers and we want to upgrade one to version 1.2.x
It's possible to upgrade one DC and work with a mixed version cluster?
Thanks

Comment: Since the Planet Cassandra site QA redirects to StackOverflow, I think that is unfair to mark this question as closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in the very short term as part of your upgrade but not beyond that.  In general, streaming between different Cassandra versions is not supported so you wouldn't be able to run repairs or add or remove nodes.

It is also risky because mixed version clusters aren't tested for long periods of time since the mixed version support is only designed for upgrades.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt answer Richard, is very helpful. I think is to soon for a 1.2 migration.